# Calling the default code for metaclass's __init__

Tags: python, metaclass

So I have `super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)` to call the default `__new__` function? Can I do similar for `__init__`? To call the default `__init__` function for a metaclass.

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr): # real signature unknown
        print("MyMeta.__new__ called")
        return super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print("MyMeta.__init__ called")
        ### how to call the default __init__()?
```

Comment: The same way you do it in any class: `super().__init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwdargs)`

Comment: If I do that, I will get TypeError: type.__init__() takes 1 or 3 arguments

Comment: Sorry, you should leave out `cls`. Just like you leave out `self` in any other class.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is `super().__init__(name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)` - `super()` will include the first argument (cls) automatically.
Also, there is no need to pass any parameters to `super()` (as there is no such need inside `__new__`): these are filled in automatically by the runtime.

When doing `super().__new__(...)` one have to explicitly include the first argument (the metaclass itself), because `__new__` is a static method, and super does not add any parameters automatically.

For sake of completeness: the default metaclass implementation of `__init__` (`type.__init__`) does nothing, and might just not be called at all. If you do include a `__init__` method in a metaclass, though, it is important to call it with `super()` so that your metaclass can be used cooperatively with other metaclasses in case it is needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MetaClass(type):
    """
    Class is object. By default, "type" created the in memory class object.
    Instance is object. Class created the in memory instance object.
    """
    meta_counter = 0

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        print("***MyMeta.__new__(): control class object creation")
        cls_object = super(MetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)
        return cls_object

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print("***MyMeta.__init__() class-wide initializer")
        cls.cls_order = MetaClass.meta_counter
        MetaClass.meta_counter += 1


class AClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("AClass.__init__()")


class BClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass


class XClass:
    def __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
        print("ZClass.__new__(): constructor")
        instance = super(XClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("ZClass.__init__(): instance-wide initializer")
        self.id = 1


print("\n\n---> ")
a = AClass()
print(a.cls_order)
b = BClass()
print(b.cls_order)

print(MetaClass.meta_counter)

print("\n\n***> ")
XClass('my-name')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be at all relevant to the question. Can you add some explanatory text to say how this code-only answer relates to using `super().__init__` in a metaclass?